# Raspberry pi B+'s usb port is not working after downgrading linux kernel (on raspbian) to 3.10.xx

Tags: bluetooth, usb, kernel, raspberry-pi, downgrade

We need to use bluetooth on Raspberry pi B+ (kernel version : 3.12.25+).

But it didn't work. And after surfing the internet, we found that we need to downgrade a kernel to 3.10.xx

So we did it as it said.

But after downgrading kernel, suddenly usb ports didn't work (Ethernet port didn't work also).

So we couldn't use a bluetooth dongle what we bought.

Please help us for enable usb ports..! (also, how to communicate raspberry pi and other bluetooth devices(for example, HC-06) on latest version of raspbian...(higher than 3.12 kernel vesion))

(Bluetooth Dongle Model : NEXT-204BT)